# Get a random index of a value from a tensor

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a tensor of tensors that contain some numeric values:

```
[ [0,0,0,1,1,1], [1,2,1,0,1,0] ... ]
```

for each of the tensors i would like to get a random index of a zero value.
so for the first tensor possible output values are `0,1,2` for the second tensor possible values are `3,5`. (i only want one from each of these possible outcomes at random so something like `[0,5]`)

What is the best way to accomplish this in tensorflow?

Comment: Can there be negative numbers in the data? (that is, is `0` always going to be the smallest possible value?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible solution:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Input data
nums = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None])
rows = tf.shape(nums)[0]
# Number of zeros on each row
zero_mask = tf.cast(tf.equal(nums, 0), tf.int32)
num_zeros = tf.reduce_sum(zero_mask, axis=1)
# Random values
r = tf.random_uniform([rows], 0, 1, dtype=tf.float32)
# Multiply by the number of zeros to decide which of the zeros you pick
zero_idx = tf.cast(tf.floor(r * tf.cast(num_zeros, r.dtype)), tf.int32)
# Find the indices of the smallest values, which should be the zeros
_, zero_pos = tf.nn.top_k(-nums, k=tf.maximum(tf.reduce_max(num_zeros), 1))
# Select the corresponding position of each row
result = tf.gather_nd(zero_pos, tf.stack([tf.range(rows), zero_idx], axis=1))
# Test
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = [[0,0,0,1,1,1],
         [1,2,1,0,1,0]]
    print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={nums: x}))
    print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={nums: x}))
    print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={nums: x}))
```

Example output:

```
[1 3]
[2 5]
[0 3]
```

If some row does not have any zero then it will pick the index 0, although you can make a mask to filter those with something like:

```
has_zeros = tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(nums, 0), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! This will work for me. Ill leave the question open for a little bit just in case someone comes up with a general solution that works for negative numbers as well but i will mark your answer soon if no one does.

Comment: @Xitcod13 Thanks for the comment, your are right. I updated the solution though, fixing an error and changing it slightly so it works for any value without more work.